# $\Omega(\mathbb{Z} \times BGL_{\infty}) \simeq GL_{\infty}$?

Tags: topological-k-theory, k-theory

Could somebody help to explain the homotopy equivalence $\Omega(\mathbb{Z} \times BGL_{\infty}) \simeq GL_{\infty}$?  Dan Freed in his [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/Notes/lecture14.pdf) pp.7 says it is trivially true but I can't see it.

Comment: *Where* in the several pages of those notes is that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: on page 7, "It is trivial that $\Omega(\mathbb{Z} \times BGL_{\infty}) \simeq GL_{\infty}$, and the two statements together immediately imply Bott periodicity."

Comment: $BG$ satisfies $\Omega BG \cong G$ more or less by definition, depending on your definition of $BG$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: sorry, I forgot the page number, it is on pp.7

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: you mean combining $\mathbb{Z} \times BGL_{\infty} \simeq BGL_{\infty}$ and $\Omega{BGL_{\infty}} \simeq GL_{\infty}$?

Comment: @Physics: Taking the loop space of a pointed space is only sensitive to the identity component, so the $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: got you!  Many thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question, which was answered in the comments: $\Omega(\mathbb{Z}\times BG)=\Omega(BG)$ for groups $G$, as the based loop space functor only depends on the pathconnected component containing the basepoints. More or less by definitition $\Omega(BG)\cong G$, which implies the result of the question.